# Force IIS to prompt for credentials

Tags: iis, authentication, windows-authentication, asp.net-mvc

We have a website that should only be accessed by authenticated active directory users.  The first thing that should happen when entering the site is a prompt to enter windows credentials.

To accomplish this, we've only enabled windows authentication and turned impersonation on.

It looks like this in the config:

```xml
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
</system.web>
```

Which shows up like this in IIS:

[image: authentication]

**But**, whenever I navigate to the page, I am not prompted credentials and it uses the server name as the user instead.

What else can I change?

We're using Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
We're using Internet Information Services v 8.5
This is an ASP.NET MVC application using .NET 4.5 Integrated

I'm hoping to get this as soon as someone hits the page:
[image: prompt]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our issue was actually that we were using [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://web.archive.org/web/20160211180023/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/06/integrated-windows-authentication-kerberos-ntlm-http-400-error-for-16kb-authorization-header.aspx) which automatically passed the credentials of the logged on user to the server.

In order to prompt the user for credentials, we enabled [Basic Authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) to pass the login information to the server, which then used the login info and windows active directory to authenticate.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved, Fixed - I'll delete this comment in 24hrs

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```xml
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

Restart the web server and it should prompt you for login/password.